# Using Sherlock Action Bar but default actionbar still exists

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I've installed successfully Sherlock's Action Bar and the 2 items i've added are placed well!
But it appears that Sherlock has not replaced the default android action bar, and i always get an android image on the left :/ 
How can i remove it? Or replace it? 
I want to place on the left my app's name - with some action - but i can't and don't know how, if Sherlock does not work well.
Please help! :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can set an icon and a title, and listen for the item click:

```
// in onResume
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();

bar.setTitle( "My App Name" );

bar.setHomeButtonEnabled( true );

bar.setIcon( R.drawable.your_icon );

// later
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected( int featureId, MenuItem item )
{
  if( android.R.id.home == item.getItemId() )
  {
    // do your stuff here

    return true;
  }

  return super.onMenuItemSelected( featureId, item );
}
```

Comment: @BabisE.Kalogiannakis: Not a problem, glad to help! Do make sure you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) though, and upvote relevante answers, and accept the most helpful! Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the icon with `actionbar.setIcon()` or you can remove it completely by using `actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`.

Actionbarsherlock is only a wrapper. On Android versions where the native Actionbar is available, you will see the native one, on lower android versions you will see the actionbar provided by ABS.